# How would you characterize the phrase 'a more perfect union'?

Tags: analogy, metaphors, comparisons, figures-of-speech, rhetoric

My question pertains to the usage of 'a more perfect union' in its original context-- the preamble to the U.S. Constitution.

I want to say that this is a metaphor, because the authors are using the word 'union' in a specific figurative sense.

However, this seems a bit strong, because it's not a comparison between two distinct objects. Rather, it's an implied comparison between the state of the country, and a specific, figurative meaning of 'union' in this context.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the interpretation of historical political literature.

Comment: Isn't 'perfect' one of those words like 'unique' which is not gradable. In other words, is it possible for the Union to be more or less perfect? Either it is perfect or it isn't. I am not sure who wrote the preamble. But if it was Thomas Jefferson his English wasn't perhaps his strongest suit. The Declaration of Independence talks about the colonists 'unalienable rights'. I am sure they should have beeen 'inalienable rights'.

Comment: "More perfect" is just an exaggeration. Nothing is ever perfect and to have the sense of entitlement to use perfect invites the use of "more perfect".

Comment: Logically speaking, your objection is valid, but much of rhetoric is logically "incorrect," often intentionally. I'm not asking about the modifier of 'more perfect', that much is clear; my focus is on the status of "union".

Comment: "Perfect", like many other words in English, has more than one meaning. Sometimes it is an absolute, incapable of comparison. Another, possibly more common, meaning does allow comparison.

Comment: @Ingmar: Yeah, consider Martha Stewart, for example. Have you ever counted how many times she uses the word "perfect" in one of her television shows? "Hey, Martha, here's your perfection!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that the authors intended "a more perfect union" quite literally.

Remember, when the Constitution was composed a legal union, bearing that name, was already in effect, *de facto* since the *Articles of Confederation and Perpetual Union* were drafted in 1777 and *de jure* since they were ratified by the final state, Maryland, in 1781. The original purpose of the Philadelphia Convention was to amend the by then patent imperfections of the Articles—in the words of the final report of the “Annapolis Convention”—formally, the Commissioners to Remedy Defects of the Federal Government:

> Your Commissioners, with the most respectful deference, beg leave to suggest their unanimous conviction, that it may essentially tend to advance the interests of the **union**, if the States, by whom they have been respectively delegated, would themselves concur, and use their endeavours to procure the concurrence of the other States, in the appointment of Commissioners, to meet at Philadelphia on the second Monday in May next, to take into consideration the situation of the United States, to devise such further provisions as shall appear to them necessary to render the constitution of the Federal Government adequate to the exigencies of the **Union**; and to report such an Act for that purpose to the United States in Congress assembled, as when agreed to, by them, and afterwards confirmed by the Legislatures of every State, will effectually provide for the same. [*my emphasis*]

Comment: Ah, excellent. This sheds light on the ambiguity in my original question. I was curious about how one would describe the figure of speech I assumed 'a more perfect union' to be; viewed in this light my assumption was incorrect, and the original meaning was more literal. Both answers were helpful, I'm accepting this one due to research.

Answer (score 3):

I would agree that this is not a metaphor.

It seems, on first glance, to be a logical impossibility: if something is perfect already, how can it be made 'more perfect'? However, on reflection, it becomes clearer that this particular phrase meant *closer to perfection*, which is neither metaphor, analogy, simile or other. If anything, I'd agree it was a comparison between the union that existed, and an imagined better one.